# Installing the Jenkins agent service by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2012-r2, jenkins-agent

- Jenkins: 1.642.2
- agent Windows 2012 R2
- JDK 1.7

In the Windows agent I check the service .msc but I don't find the Jenkins agent service, when I open manage node in the Manage Jenkins I click: Bring this node back online I have this log:

```
[windows-slaves] Connecting to WS8888
Checking if Java exists
java -version returned 1.7.0.
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Installing the Jenkins slave service
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.exe
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Copying slave.jar
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.xml
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Registering the service
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Starting the service
[2016-09-29 14:44:52] [windows-slaves] Waiting for the service to become ready
[2016-09-29 14:44:57] [windows-slaves] Connecting to port 56,783
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 2.53.3
This is a Windows slave
```

I check the service.msc I find the service: "Jenkins Slave at F:\slave_jenkins"
but when I stop the agent from Jenkins the service disappears

I tried to delete the service and create a new service doesn't work and if I restart the agent from ManageNodes the service is created but is not stable is disconnected every 10 hours

Comment: Did you try this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Answer (score 0):

In the slave machine try install the slave service with the jenkins user. it may solve the issue.

Comment: it's a Windows slave

Comment: yes, you can install a slave service in windows machine (master can be in linux) check the slave folder configured in slave configuration(folder created in slave machine(windows)). if not create the folder in slave machine and verify jenkins-slave.exe is available in the folder

Comment: if you still face this issue try to install service via command line